# How to make table like picture?

Tags: tables

I'm trying to make the table in the picture, without any result.
Can someone help me ?
Thanks[image]

Comment: Try searching here for “use case”

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) On this site, a question should typically revolve around an abstract issue (e.g. "How do I get a double horizontal line in a table?") rather than a concrete application (e.g. "How do I make this table?"). Questions that look like "Please do this complicated thing for me" tend to get closed because they are either "off topic", "too broad", or "unclear". Please try to make your question clear and simple by giving a [minimal working example (MWE)](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228): you'll stand a greater chance of getting help.

Comment: What did you try?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do this could be:

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{multirow,booktabs,array}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}

\newcommand\onecell[2][c]{\begin{tabular}{@{}#1@{}}#2\end{tabular}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}[]{>{\bfseries}l>{\itshape}l}
  \toprule
  \onecell[l]{\MakeUppercase{Caso d'uso}:\\\normalfont\textit{Codice}} &
  \onecell[l@{\hskip7em}l]{\multirow{2}{*}{Nome del caso d'uso}
    & \normalfont\textbf{Data:}\\
    & \normalfont\textbf{Versione:} 0.00.000}\\
  \midrule
  \textcolor{Olive}{Descrizione}:
    & \textcolor{Olive}{Descrizione} generale del caso d'uso (scope).\\
  Priorit\`a:
    & Priorit\`a attribuita al caso d'uso dagli utenti.\\
  Durata:
    & Ordine di grandezza stimata della durata del caso d'uso.\\
  Attore primario:
    & Nome\\
    & Interessi nell'esecuzione del caso d'uso\\
  \textcolor{Olive}{Attori} secondari:
    & Nome\\
    & Interessi nell'esecuzione del caso d'uso\\
  \textcolor{Olive}{Precondizioni}:
    & \textcolor{Olive}{Descrizione.}\\
  Garanzie:
    & some text covered\\
    & by a tooltip\\
  Avvio:
    & Evento che innesca l'avvio del caso d'uso\\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Without the usage of `multirow` but a `\onecell` more (result is the same):

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{booktabs,array}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}

\newcommand\onecell[2][c]{\begin{tabular}{@{}#1@{}}#2\end{tabular}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}[]{>{\bfseries}l>{\itshape}l}
  \toprule
  \onecell[l]{\MakeUppercase{Caso d'uso}:\\\normalfont\textit{Codice}} &
  \onecell[l@{\hskip7em}l]{Nome del caso d'uso
    & \onecell[>{\normalfont}l]{\textbf{Data:}\\\textbf{Versione:} 0.00.000}
  }\\
  \midrule
  \textcolor{Olive}{Descrizione}:
    & \textcolor{Olive}{Descrizione} generale del caso d'uso (scope).\\
  Priorit\`a:
    & Priorit\`a attribuita al caso d'uso dagli utenti.\\
  Durata:
    & Ordine di grandezza stimata della durata del caso d'uso.\\
  Attore primario:
    & Nome\\
    & Interessi nell'esecuzione del caso d'uso\\
  \textcolor{Olive}{Attori} secondari:
    & Nome\\
    & Interessi nell'esecuzione del caso d'uso\\
  \textcolor{Olive}{Precondizioni}:
    & \textcolor{Olive}{Descrizione.}\\
  Garanzie:
    & some text covered\\
    & by a tooltip\\
  Avvio:
    & Evento che innesca l'avvio del caso d'uso\\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```